# 2003 Subaru Outback central locking

Tags: troubleshooting, central-locking

I was wondering why the central locking on the key(buttons) are so hard to push and there is no response to me pushing the lock/unlock on the key. It happens not all the time but 8/10 so a lot. It shouldn’t be that hard to get a response from these buttons and I’m hoping it’s only the battery. It wasn’t the exact correct battery but it works occasionally so I assumed it would be finehelpthank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The buttons can get dirty / intermittent on these fobs - which usually means replacement : there are some people who can replace buttons or you can buy new fobs complete (warning - cheap ones may have a very short life...).

When you mention the battery - have you replaced it with one of the correct size? If not that could be part or all of the problem...

Comment: So do you mean the buttons need replacing or is there some way of cleaning them or making less stiffer for pressing?

Comment: you can try cleaning the buttons, but some are small and challenging... electrical cleaning fluid / spray may be worth trying, if not, then replace...

Comment: Replace with the correct battery, making sure the battery connections in the fob and the battery faces are all clean and dry.